# Tooltip not working on Dynamically created elements with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I have created some dynamic html elements (spam , divs) using an Ajax response. I have placed the tooltip code on those elements but it doesn't seem to shoe any of the tooltips.
here's the code I have so far:

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'get_form.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {idFormulario: idFormulario},
                success :  function(response)
                {      
                
                console.log(response);
                var json = $.parseJSON(response);
                var num = json.length;
                    
                html +='<table class="table" cellpadding="2">';
                
                for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
                    
                    var index = i+1;
                    var pregunta = json[i].pregunta;

                    html += '<tr>'+
                    '<td width=50%>'+
                    '<a href="#" class="pregunta"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="'json[i].pregunta'" >'+pregunta+'</a></td>'+
                    
                    '</tr>';
                    $('.pregunta').tooltip(); 
                    
                     }
                
                html += '</table>';
                }
                
                $('.summernote').summernote('code', html);
                
          });
```

Why tootilp is not working on thise created element? Thanks in advance

Comment: `$('.pregunta').tooltip();` you're running this before you add the HTML to the DOM - it won't magically apply to your `html+=` *string*.   Move `.tooltip()` to after `summernote(..)` (at a guess)

Comment: Thank you I have move it after summernote(...) but still won't show the tooltip, any other suggestions?

Comment: Next step will be to provide us with enough code to reproduce the issue in the question - that means whatever you are suing for `.summernote` and for `.tooltip()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_form.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {idFormulario: idFormulario},
    success :  function(response)
    {      
    
    console.log(response);
    var json = $.parseJSON(response);
    var num = json.length;
        
    html +='<table class="table" cellpadding="2">';
    
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        
        var index = i+1;
        var pregunta = json[i].pregunta;

        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td width=50%><a href="#" class="pregunta"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-title="'+json[i].pregunta+'" >'+pregunta+'</a></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
       
     }
    
    html += '</table>';
    }
    
    $('.summernote').summernote('code', html);
    $('.pregunta').tooltip(); 
    
});
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**